# Concrete5.7 Stacks - PHP Maximum execution time exceeded

Tags: php, regex, backreference, concrete5-5.7

We are having an odd issue with Stacks in Concrete5.7: we are starting to collect quite a few stacks (64 currently) and our server has started throwing server errors (`PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /example/path/to/website/concrete/blocks/html/controller.php on line 89`) when editing pages, specifically when getting `/ccm/system/panels/add?cID=2468&tab=stacks` via XHR.

I temporarily solved this by increasing `max_execution_time` from 30 to 60 in `php.ini`, but this seems like a poor workaround that I will have to again bump after adding more content to Stacks.

## Is there something else I can do besides just blindly increasing `max_execution_time`?

Tracing into `blocks/html/controller.php:89`, that is in the `xml_highlight()` function; specifically, this line ([see the code in context here](http://documentation.concrete5.org/api/source-class-Concrete.Block.Html.Controller.html#89)):

```
    $s = preg_replace(
        "#&lt;(.*)(\[)(.*)(\])&gt;#isU",
        "&lt;\\1<font color=\"#800080\">\\2\\3\\4</font>&gt;",
        $s
    );
```

This seems like a fairly straightforward regex to me; am I missing something?

It also occurs to me that I could remove all the `preg_replace` calls from `xml_highlight()` and check performance, but I am unsure what functionality I would be losing by doing so.

For reference, from `dashboard/system/environment/info`:

```
# concrete5 Version
Core Version - 5.7.5.2
Version Installed - 5.7.5.2
Database Version - 20150731000000
```

Comment: What is `"#&lt;(.*)(\[)(.*)(\])&gt;#isU"` supposed to match? You might try changing it to `"#&lt;([^[]*)(\[)([^]]*)(])&gt;#i"` and see if it helps. All the regexps there are `.`-based, which is not good when you deal with marked up text.

Comment: It's always a bad sign when a regex author appends the `U` option to every regex, as if it were a magical blue pill that solves all performance problems.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think the `s` option might be necessary though, as the matched code is/could be HTML with (user-entered) line breaks.

Comment: @MattRice, `s` option makes no sense when a pattern has no `.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with that regex is that it has two instances of `.*` in it, and the `s` option at the end that lets `.` match newlines.

That means, after it finds a `&lt;` it has to scan potentially the whole rest of the text looking for `[`, and then again looking for `]&gt;`.  The `U` option means it will try the shortest matches first, but it will keep trying until it finds a match or eliminates all possibilities.  And it will do that for every `&lt;` in the document.

Changing the regex as [Wiktor suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43477969/concrete5-7-stacks-php-maximum-execution-time-exceeded#comment74012708_43477969) should solve the problem, but I would take it a step further and use possessive quantifiers:

```
"#&lt;([^[]*+)(\[)([^]]*+)(\])&gt;#i"
```

The other regexes in that function are just as badly written, but they contain at most one `.*` each, so they don't try to crash the system.

Comment: Are you missing an escape character in capture group 4 (the right square bracket)? i.e. should `(])` be `(\])`?

Comment: Yes and no.  It should work as is, but I usually escape it anyway, because some flavors insist on it.  This time I just copy-pasted it out of RegexBuddy, where I composed it.  I'll go ahead and escape it, just to be safe.